# "Error establishing a database connection" Wordpress after I installed a new database

Tags: database, wordpress

I was making a website through WordPress and everything was ok; the DB was on the port 3306.
Two days ago, I had to install a DB on my pc for my job and it is on port 3306 so I changed the Wordpress's Db port into 3316 in my.ini but since then when I open my WP website it appears this:
Error establishing a database connection

What else am I supposed to change?

It's important that the db of my job stays on port 3306

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the MySQL port in `wp-config.php`; WP is looking for the port there, rather than in my.ini.

Try:

> For localhost:
>
> define( 'DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1:3316' );
>
> or in some cases:
>
> define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost:3316' );
>
> For specified server:
>
> define( 'DB_HOST', 'mysql.example.com:3316' );

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#MySQL_Alternate_Port